# PHP - Date and Time display issue

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I hope that you may have a hint for me, how I can solve this issue. I am showing to my customers some kind of a ranking list. The data within the ranking list are really important and the ranking list counts all selected points from tuesday for 2 weeks until monday last week. Everything is working so far, except when today is tuesday, because with my function, the program shows on tuesday the ranking list for the last two weeks except from last week.

Here is my code I am using:

```
$start_date_week=strtotime('-2 week tuesday 00:00:00');
$end_date_week=strtotime('-1 week monday 23:59:59');
```

So if today is tuesday, my program shows me the data from the last 2 weeks. On every other day it shows the data from last week correct. Any idea how I can make this work, even if today is tuesday?

With those 2 variables I am getting my data from the database and those two variabes also show the date from until the date to:

```
.date("d.m.Y", $start_date_week)." - ".date("d.m.Y", $end_date_week)."
```

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: why not run a simple query for if date = tuesday and run a query to display the 2 week log and then use the else to display the 1 week log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this here as I feel you're over thinking something that could be simplified:

```
$timestamp = time();
if (date('D', $timestamp) === 'Tue')
{
    // run a database query for 2 weeks of logs
    echo "2 week log";
} else {
    // run database query for 1 week of logs
    echo "1 week log";
}
```

Comment: that´s a very good hint. You are right, I was over thinking that way. I do not need the 2 week log, I always just need 1 week log but I can use your if statement to check if it is tuesday and if it is tuesday he should get me the log from tuesday 1 week ago and if today is not tuesday he should give me the log from tuesday 2 weeks ago. This is how it should work I guess. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: No problem. If you feel this answer was correct please confirm its the best answer for you.